# Feature toggle CMS Content

Tags: content-delivery

We have a requirement where we need to make lots and lots of legally mandated content throughout the site. This also requires a significant content tree and data source restructure.

And this content needs to be published only on specified date e.g. 1st Feb 2019. This content changes will take hours and another few hours for testing etc.

Options below:

1. Restore prod content to UAT and make content changes a couple of weeks eariler. This mean content change needs to be freezed otherwise it will lead to in-consistency.
2. Make changes directly in prod week earlier. Same issue as above.
3. make changes as part day of release. Too many changes which leads to error and testing impacts.

Does sitecore provide any feature out of box to solve this type of scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Just brainstorming here, but one way of approaching this would be to go with a 'multisite' scenario, which could be risky depending on how many hard-coded GUIDs you are using.

A secondary site with the new structure and content can be set up, completely published, and ready to go. When you are ready to swap, the host mappings can be updated so your new content path resolves instead of the old one.

If you need to share content, you could use 'clones', I suppose. This would make sure edits from the original content translate over to your new site, but you can have the items in a different structure.

If you didn't have the restructuring happening, i.e. you were only editing the items content and presentation, versioning and workflow would allow you to do this. As soon as you need to physically alter the tree structure of the content you can't use the built-in item versioning for that and need to have a different tree somewhere.

Post-launch you could then slowly replace your clones with the original items and retire the old content tree path.

Comment: Thanks, content restructures are very minimum. Would you be able to expand on how version and workflow would help? Given its prod content change which we would like to do week earlier and at same time allow authors to make other changes and publish except legal changes

Comment: you can add new versions of items with publishing restritions on those versions of the items, so they don't go live until the requied date. Do the authors need to make other changes to those same item? If so they would either need to be an admin to change the previous version. Or would need to copy the currently live version to a new version after the legal scheduled one, and make that version expire before the new legal one is scheduled to show up, so the previous version with the legal changes gets published.